# Move value from multiple select to another select

Tags: jquery, select

I've got 2 multiple select - I can get it to move the option I click on in .select-cities, to .chosen-cities, however, it doesnt work the other way? Any ideas to why not?

```
//Move cities to div
$jq('.select-cities option').click(function () {
    return !$jq('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');
});

$jq('.chosen-cities option').click(function () {
    alert(this);
    $jq('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');
});
```

The HTML:

```
<select class="select-cities" name="city" multiple="multiple">
                <option>Frederiksberg</option>
                <option>Vanløse</option>
                <option>Glostrup</option>
                <option>Brøndby</option>
                <option>Roskilde</option>
                <option>Køge</option>
                <option>Gentofte</option>
                <option>Hillerød</option>
                <option>Tårnby</option>
                <option>Vallensbæk</option>
            </select>

<select class="chosen-cities" name="chosen-cities-name" multiple="multiple">

            </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.select-cities').click(function () {
    $('.select-cities option:selected').appendTo('.chosen-cities');
});

$('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
    $('.chosen-cities option:selected').appendTo('.select-cities');
});
```

[jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/) sample

Comment: The option needs to move, not be duplicated, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @Anthony Atkinson: check the fiddler sample, this move the option from one side to the other :)

Answer (score 1):

The selector on option does not fire a click event

Here is a possible work around
http://jsfiddle.net/nDvch/1/

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use the jQuery live() function to ensure that the click event applies for all elements matching the selector, even when those elements change: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Sorry apparently I was unaware that the .live() function has been deprecated in favor of .on(). My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I wouldn't use `$jq('.chosen-cities option').click` but `$jq('.chosen-cities').change(function () {`.

And for your actual question: remove() also removes all event listeners. Better use [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign click event to the "select" element. Not to "option".

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fBd5z/